# Was it pinged successfully?

Tags: php, xml, ping

I've used this php file
http://www.barattalo.it/2010/02/24/ping-pingomatic-com-services-with-php/

and this is the debugging info :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 09 Apr 2012 17:36:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 345
X-Cache: MISS from proxy34.samanet.sy
X-Cache-Lookup: MISS from proxy34.samanet.sy:3128
Via: 1.0 proxy34.samanet.sy (squid/3.0.STABLE19)
Proxy-Connection: close

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodResponse>
  <params>
    <param>
      <value>
        <struct>
  <member><name>flerror</name><value><boolean>0</boolean></value></member>
  <member><name>message</name><value><string>Pings being forwarded to 10 services!</string></value></member>
</struct>
      </value>
    </param>
  </params>
</methodResponse>
```

does the result mean everything worked?  If not, what is the error?

Comment: you got `200 OK` code that =success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the signification of HTTP Status Code from [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

And by the way your log says that everything is ok, i quote :

> **10.2.1 200 OK**
>
> The request has succeeded. The information returned with the response
> is dependent on the method used in the request, for example:
>
> GET an entity corresponding to the requested resource is sent in the
> response;
>
> HEAD the entity-header fields corresponding to the requested resource
> are sent in the response without any message-body;
>
> POST an entity describing or containing the result of the action;
>
> TRACE an entity containing the request message as received by the end
> server.

Comment: And if you prefere french (peut être ^^) : http://www.commentcamarche.net/contents/internet/http.php3#les-codes-de-reponse